# NDEF P2P exchange large file data

Tags: android, nfc

I develop about NDEF P2P but have a question. 
Can NDEF P2P exchange large file data like movie media, audio media, raw binary?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NDEF P2P *can* exchange larger data but it's not really designed for that.

Its main use case is in NFC, in which the transfer rate ranges around 420 kbit/s, which is relatively slow.  You wouldn't want to transfer a large file at that speed.  Transferring even one megabyte would take upwards of 20 seconds.  Having to keep the two devices within 1-3 inches for that long is unwieldy.

The recommended solution to transferring large data is to use NFC to set up a secondary connection, usually bluetooth, which is faster and also has the benefit of allowing the devices to be farther apart.  Here's an article on how to set up bluetooth on android via NFC:

http://fupeg.blogspot.com/2011/06/local-data-exchange-with-nfc-and.html

Comment: 420kbit is technically correct (almost, ballpark figure), but due to protocol overhead the real speed will be more in the range of 16kbit/s. E.g. a transfer of two kilobytes will take a second. NFC is not fast :-)